# Application in ACS (DCOS) on any other port except 80

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, marathon, dcos, azure-container-service

How can I host an application in ACS (DCOS) on any other port except 80? Can I give any other URL instead of using port number to access?

```json
{
 "id": "/dockercloud-hello-world",
 "cmd": null,
 "cpus": 0.1,
 "mem": 128,
 "disk": 0,
 "instances": 2,
 "acceptedResourceRoles": [
   "*"
 ],
 "container": {
   "type": "DOCKER",
   "volumes": [],
   "docker": {
     "image": "dockercloud/hello-world",
     "network": "BRIDGE",
     "portMappings": [
       {
         "containerPort": 80,
         "hostPort": 0,
         "servicePort": 10000,
         "protocol": "tcp",
         "labels": {}
       }
     ],
     "privileged": false,
     "parameters": [],
     "forcePullImage": true
   }
 },

 "portDefinitions": [
   {
     "port": 10000,
     "protocol": "tcp",
     "name": "default",
     "labels": {}
   }
 ]
}
```

Application is available on port 4170 according to Marathon.

I am unable to access from agents fqn:portnumber

Comment: I have tried adding all the rules mentioned in the URL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-enable-public-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Firstly, you need modify `hostPort` value to `4170` and `acceptedResourceRoles` to `slave_public`.

Then you need open port 4170 on agent node NSG.

[image]

Then you also need open port on agent node LB.

1.Add Health probes

[image]

2.Load balancing rules

[image]

More information about this please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-enable-public-access).

Comment: I test in my lab, it works for me. You could access my image http://shuidcagents.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com:4170/

Comment: I have tried working on suggestions provided still unable to view 
https://imgur.com/a/mW6dX

Comment: @user2547194 It seems no issue for your configuration,  what is your agent ip?

Comment: If you try listen your container on 8080(the port is open on default)? what is the result?

Comment: I did not change "acceptedResourceRoles": [
      "*"
    ] to slave_public. After change its working. Thanks for the support.

can we have a differnt url like helloworld.dcos.com?

Comment: Ok. can we have a different url like helloworld.dcos.com instead of accessing from the port numbers??
Will scaling of the application be a problem when we are using static ports?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166374/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-user2547194).